# jquery - inpage scroll smooth links with button next and prev

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I found this [site](http://www.clarefraser.com/) and i want the way it work but unfortunately I have less knowledge in jquery but I know how to do simple modification to make it work,

my current js code is here:

```
$(".fadeScroll").click(function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          //calculate destination place
          var dest = 0;
          if ($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
              dest = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
          } else {
              dest = $(this.hash).offset().top;
          }
          //go to destination
          $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: dest
          }, 2000, 'swing');
      });
```

but it only do is to scroll smoothly (*inpage Links*), the next button its not working and I have no idea what the next thing to do. I like this effect of this [site](http://www.clarefraser.com/) because it give the visitor the Idea on what content he/she is, because of the menu have `active state` also next and prev button coordinate with the `menu` and work nicely

Here my current [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/4k8VR/3/)

HOPE THIS MAKE SENSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your markup and script to do what you want. One of the main issues was that you were using the same class name on the prev & next buttons...

The updated script uses a single function to control the scrolling. The various buttons update the item index to scroll to, then call that function.

[here's your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4k8VR/9/).
and your updated JS.

```
var itemIndex = 1;
function scrollToContent() {

    //dont allow zero or greater than 5
    if (itemIndex <= 1) {
        itemIndex = 1;
        $('#fade').hide();
    }
    else{
        $('#fade').show();
    }
    if (itemIndex >= 5) {
        itemIndex = 5;
        $('#fade1').hide();
    }
    else{
        $('#fade1').show();
    }
    //scroll
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop : $('#content' + itemIndex).offset().top
    }, 2000);
    //add & remove active class name
    $('button.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.navigation li:nth-child(' + itemIndex + ') button').addClass('active');
}

//click handlers
function clickFuncs() {
    $(".navigation button").click(function() {
        itemIndex = $(this).attr('data-index');
        scrollToContent();
    });

    $('#fade1').click(function() {++itemIndex;
        scrollToContent();
    });

    $('#fade').click(function() {--itemIndex;
        scrollToContent();
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {

    //setup click handlers
    clickFuncs();

});
```

updated HTML

```
<ul class="navigation">
<li><button data-index="1">content1</button></li>
<li><button data-index="2">content2</button></li>
<li><button data-index="3">content3</button></li>
<li><button data-index="4">content4</button></li>
<li><button data-index="5">content5</button></li>    
</ul>

<p class="buttons">
   <button id="fade">prev</button>
   <button id="fade1">next</button> 
</p>
```

Comment: almost there thanks, but prev button must hide in default just like http://www.clarefraser.com and also even the next and prev button/links also left links have and `active state`

Comment: it's almost there, thank you for the support is that possible to hide the `prev button` in default, and in `last` also hide `next button` is that possible your just like http://www.clarefraser.com/

Comment: wow this is very good one!! thank you but one thing, can I use simple `<a href="#"></a>` or anchor not work it should be `button` to work like this.

Comment: yes of course you could change it back to <a> tags, and then just update the JS and CSS to match...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49196/discussion-between-lukeocom-and-jhunlio)