# jquery animate a scroll but not on exact position where the id is since my nav is fixed at the top

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, scroll

Basically this is a one page site with fixed header with nav on the top which obviously has height and cover the top portion when scrolled down or clicked the nav. Here is the jquery script I got here as well

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ul.navigation').on('click', 'a', function(e) {       
      e.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
      }, 2000);
   });
});
```

All good except that when I click on the nav it scrolls on the specific ID but ofcourse the element that has the id, example the h1, is being covered by the header since the header is positioned at the top most of the page. How can I adjust and at least add 185px, the size of my fixed header, on the scroll animation where the ids are positioned. Many thanks!

Comment: can you create a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I think you need this link http://cj-ramki.blogspot.in/2014/03/simple-single-page-layout-with-html-and.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just update your script to add the extra space...

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top - 185)
  }, 2000);
```

Here's an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4k8VR/12/) from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239590/jquery-inpage-scroll-smooth-links-with-button-next-and-prev/22240120#22240120)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could refer my blog post http://cj-ramki.blogspot.in/2014/03/simple-single-page-layout-with-html-and.html

get your header height from javascript,

```
var from = $("#header").height();
```

and use your animate code like below,

```
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top - from
      }, 2000);
```

**SEE FIDDLE [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/QaKrx/)**